# Unable to use multiline with pattern

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, string

I'm trying to match a string with Pattern/Matcher, however it is failing because I cannot set Pattern.MULTILINE like the Java documentation uses.

```
String testString = 'Line 1: Does not match\nCustomer Name: Bob Dole';
String regex = '^\\s*Customer Name\\s*:\\s+(.*)$';

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(testString);
Boolean hasMatch = m.matches();  //Returns false
```

According to the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) linked from the Pattern [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher.htm) on SFDC this should work:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(testString);
```

However, this gives the error `Variable does not exist: Pattern.MULTILINE`

Any ideas on how to get multiline working with Pattern?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the mode modifier `(?m)` at the beginning of your regex pattern to specify the multiline option.

```
String testString = 'Line 1: Does not match\nCustomer Name: Bob Dole';
String regex = '(?m)^\\s*Customer Name\\s*:\\s+(.*)$';

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(testString);

// iterate through testString finding subsequent matches
while (m.find()) {
    system.debug(m.start() + ': ' + m.group());
}
```

Debug output:

`DEBUG|23: Customer Name: Bob Dole`

There are a few other helpful option modifiers that can be used with the regex pattern at the beginning of the string: [regular-expressions.info - Using Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Comment: And (?s) equals Pattern.DOTALL!! Thanks for this info, did not know this!

Answer (score 6):

**Salesforce regular expressions are multiline out of the box.** Here's a fragment for your requirement:

```
String search = Pattern.quote('Customer Name:');
String subject = 'Line 1: Does not match\nCustomer Name: Bob Dole\n123-456-789';

Pattern jsonish = Pattern.compile(
  search      //the search term escaped for regex
  + '\\s+'    //one or more whitespaces
  + '('       //start capturing
  + '[^\\n]+' //one or more of anything other than a newline
  + ')'       //stop capturing
  + '\\n'     //exactly one newline
);
Matcher matcher = jsonish.matcher(subject);
System.assert(matcher.find());                     //true,
System.assertEquals('Bob Dole', matcher.group(1)); //works!
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with using Regex, SF only supports pattern matching in general, not **ALL** Java options will work with Apex pattern matching. In this particular case, as the error message is telling you, multiline pattern matching is not a feature that's built into the Apex compiler. Instead, you'll need to do a pattern search as part of your regular-expression to find the multi-line symbols.

I recommend you look at [string methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm?) and perform string operations first to either split the multi-line strings into single lines before doing your matching, or else simply perform a remove operation on the entire string for the multiline/carriage return symbols. Of course you could include a search for the multi-line symbols/characters as part of your regular-expression too! You have a number of options, its a matter of deciding what will work best for your particular situation.